# Is "sonar.jdbc.url" mandatory?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I'm setting up a build agent with the SonarQube runner to report results to a SonarQube server installation that is placed in a restricted Environment.

Is it possible, somehow, to report without having a direct connection to the database (i.e. specify sonar.jdbc.url)? If not, is there a reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not currently possible. But version 5.2 will remove this direct connection with the database (version 5.2 is currently available as Release Candidate).